# How to catch output of bash script and import it to another?

Tags: linux, bash, youtube, type-conversion

On my Arch Linux PC, I've downloaded the package `youtube-dl` from the official repositories. When I use it to download YouTube videos in mp4 format, the result looks like this (I'll be using '$' to indicate the shell prompt):

```
`$ youtube-dl --format mp4 https://www.examplelink.com`

[youtube] Q0CbN8sfihY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Q0CbN8sfihY: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] Q0CbN8sfihY: Extracting video information
[youtube] Q0CbN8sfihY: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Destination: ExampleVideo.mp4
[download] 100% of 15.07MiB in 00:20`
```

I'm hoping to catch the video title from this output, and import it into another script, which looks like this:

```
`#! /bin/bash`

`track=`echo "$@"`
music='/home/samuel/Music/'
video='/home/samuel/Videos/'
ffmpeg -i "$video$track".mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 160k -ar 44100 -ac 2 "$music$track".mp3`
```

This will convert the `.mp4` file to `.mp3` format, and in turn, create a completely automated process. How would you catch the name of the video title and import it into the other script?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to catch the name of the downloaded file? Is the output just going to stdout? Assuming your script name is `nameIt`, try this -

```
youtube-dl --format mp4 https://www.examplelink.com 2>&1 |  
  tee whole.log     |  # save the whole log just in case
  grep Destination: |  # pass only the relevant line through
  { read x x file; nameIt $file }
```

Most folk would say use awk - I'll let them offer ways to do that.
The `{ ... }` around the read/echo are because `read` scopes the var to the pipeline. Instead of echo, you could pass it to your other script.

You could also replace the `{ ... }` with `sed 's/.* //'` and pipe it straight to your other script, and just catch it on stdin instead of expecting it as $1, which would look like this:

```
youtube-dl --format mp4 https://www.examplelink.com 2>&1 |  
  tee whole.log     |  # save the whole log just in case
  grep Destination: |  # pass only the relevant line through
  s/.* //'          |  # spit out the filename
  nameIt               # prog reads stdin
```

In which case your code, instead of

```
`track=`echo "$@"`
```

would just say something like

```
read track
```

Lots of ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:
The first line sets you a variable, then later I rename and move the file to remove whitespaces (can be applied to other caracters too)

`filename=$(youtube-dl --format mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgbnndezHbw|grep Destination|cut -f2 -d:) 
echo "$filename" 
newfilename="$(echo "$filename"|sed "s/^[ \t]*//"|tr ' ' '_')"
mv "$(echo "$filename"|sed 's/^ *//')" "$newfilename" 
echo "$newfilename"`

Answer (score 0):

An even better way to do this:

```
youtube-dl --exec 'echo "file: {}"'  <<URL>>
```

I used just an echo here as an example, but you can call any function you want after the download and pass it the file name with the curly brackets. Just like the find command.